# Spark Skewed Data Self Join

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark

I have a dataframe with 15 million rows and 6 columns. I need to join this dataframe with itself. However, while examining the tasks from the yarn interface, I saw that it stays at the 199/200 stage and does not progress. When I looked at the remaining 1 running jobs, I saw that almost all the data was at that stage. Later, when I execute a group by count query on the dataframe through the condition I joined, I saw that 12 million belonged to a group and the remaining 3 million were distributed into 50-60 groups.

```
Select serv,count(*) from table group by serv order by 2 desc limit 4;
"" 12.542.133
123 77000
542 75324
667 62324
```

It seems to have been skewed with the value "".
What I tried:

- In Spark 3.1 : AQE enabled, Skewjoin enabled in Spark 3 and it didn't work.
- In Spark 2.4 : tried adding a key named Salt and rejoining it with it, it still didn't work.

My Spark3 Confs :

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('v8')\
.config("spark.driver.memory", "32g") \
.config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "64g") \
.config("spark.executor.cores", "10") \
.config("spark.executor.instances", "60") \
.config('spark.executor.memory', '32g') \
.config('spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead', '32g') \
.config("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", "true") \
.config("spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled", "false") \
.config("spark.sql.adaptive.skewJoin.enabled", "true") \
.config("spark.sql.adaptive.skewJoin.skewedPartitionFactor", "30") \
.config("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", "-1") \

finaldf=df.alias("A").join(df.alias("B"), col("A.serv")==col("B.serv"),"inner") 
finaldf.count() doesnt work
```

My Spark 2.4 Confs:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('v7')\
.config("spark.driver.memory", "32g") \
.config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "64g") \
.config("spark.executor.cores", "10") \
.config("spark.executor.instances", "60") \
.config('spark.executor.memory', '32g') \
.config('spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead', '32g') \
.config("spark.port.maxRetries",32) \
.config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "300")\

I believe this approach is for skew data and normal distributed data joins but tried and failed.
numpart=number of sql shuffle partitions
dfa=df.withColumn("salt",concat(df.serv,lit("_"),lit(floor(rand() * numpart)) )  )

dfb=df.withColumn("salt_array",array([lit(i) for i in range(int(numpart))]))

dfb1=dfb.withColumn("explodCol", explode(dfb.salt_array)).drop("salt_array")

dfb2=dfb1.withColumn("salt", concat(dfb1.serv,lit("_"),dfb1.explodCol))

dffinal=dfa.alias("A").join(dfa.alias("B"),(col("A.salt")==col("B.salt"))   & (col("A.serv")==col("B.serv"))
```

What works is :

```
dfa=df.withColumn("salt",concat(df.serv,lit("_"),lit(floor(rand() * numpart)) )  )
dffinal=dfa.alias("A").join(dfb2.alias("B"),(col("A.salt")==col("B.salt"))   & (col("A.serv")==col("B.serv")) 

but Im not sure is this equal with df.join(df,(col("A.serv")==col("B.serv")))
```

Thanks for any ideas,helps.